# How to use ExtJS4 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, extjs4

I have a question about the the new ExtJS release.

I know that we can use ExtJS3 with jQuery, thanks to the adapter system (adapter folder in the library).

But in the new release, I did not find this folder. Can we always use ExtJS and jQuery at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any adapters anymore, now ExtJs is completely independent and works fine with any externals frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the answer to your question is here http://loianegroner.com/2011/08/how-to-use-extjs-4-jquery-together/